# wiki custom page layout freez the save,checkout, and page layout option?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, wiki, page-layout

I have developed the Custom Wiki page layout and deployed it successfully but once I changed the layout its freeze pagelayout, save, checkout options?

I have checked with admin/siteowner user

Run on IE, Chrome, etc browsers also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually caused by one of or a few different issues, all of which are nearly impossible to troubleshoot remotely.

1. You did not include certain required layout assets.
2. Improper markup
3. Invalid web part references.
4. Invalid system layout id references.

A couple of techniques that can be used to diagnose this further.

1. Start with the default template in sharepoint designer and keep changing slowly until you reach your final layout.
2. Wait for the page to timeout or view the console in developer tools to see if there is any details.